# Finite Difference Method for two phase fluid flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-difference-methods

I have the below set of equations and boundary conditions governing two phase fluid flow in an oil well and am struggling to start with a code to solve these with the finite difference method.

I know that I will have to manipulate the equations in order to create arrays in Matlab based on increments of r and t.

I am looking to solve for Sw as function of radial distance r.

The variables are Po, Pw, So, Sw, r & t. The rest are constants which I have expertimetnal values for.

Any help would be highly appreciated as to how to start solving.
Thanks

[Equations and boundary conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZDe2.png)

Comment: Have you solved other (simpler) PDE before? For example, advection equation?

Comment: It has been a long time since I got into advanced calc such as this. I am just trying to wrap my mind on how to start.

Comment: To begin with you need to approximate your equation, that is to convert derivatives into finite differences